# multiple imputation of longitudinal, time-unstructured data

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-imputation

I have a longitudinal dataset of radiation exposures of an occupational cohort. A percentage of the exposure values are missing and I would like to multiply impute the missing values (it is one option of several we are comparing). The data are recorded in long format (one row for each exposure entry) and there are multiple exposure measurements per worker. However, the data are time-unstructured (different data collection schedules for each worker) and unbalanced.

I want to account for the correlation between repeated measurements on the same worker. However, because of the time-unstructured nature of the dataset, I am unable to convert my dataset into wide format and impute that way. I have begun reading about about using multilevel imputation for such a scenario, but I rather unfamiliar with this approach, including within R. Is this an appropriate method to investigate?

Comment: When you say "different data collection schedules for each worker" do you mean something like one worker is tested weekly and another only monthly, or something like each worker is tested every 6 weeks but on staggered schedules, or something like each worker is tested based on suspected exposure or based on previous test values?

Comment: Workers are tested periodically (likely based on suspected exposure) but there is no visible structure to the testing schedule. For example, one worker may be tested one day per month (not necessarily on the same day each month) and the next worker may have only four tests all year. So there is no common unit of time I can assign to all workers.

Comment: Why not just make time a continuous variable?  Nothing about panel data models really requires that the time be categorical.

Comment: For the imputation part, are you looking specifically for a canned package, ir a general approach?

Answer (score 1):

The [`mi`](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v45/i02/) package might be what you are looking for.  It can accommodate longitudinal data
and works with `lmer` and `glmer` from the `lme4` mixed effects models package.  The vignette has an example of a longitudinal cohort study.